# Most efficient way to make a Histogram from an array in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, histogram

I want to count the frequency of occurrence of numbers in a double array by binning (example array below). Essentially the same functionality provided by Python [numpy's](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) `histogram()`. I'm on a constrained environment and have access to basic Java `Math` and [jblas](http://jblas.org/) library, but nothing else and no other third party libraries like [colt](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/) are installable.

`double[] x1 = {1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2}`

I have a separate sorted array which marks the start and end of the `binEdges` and looks like the following:

`binEdges = [4.9E-324, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 1.7976931348623157E308]`

Note that the `binEdges` array may have repeated elements and I would like to keep them such. Hence, with the given `binEdges` array the result of frequency count will looking like:

`binCounts = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

The `binCounts` array combined with the `binEdges`, when read from left to right is as follows, note the braces on the bin intervals:

`Bin interval   frequency 
[4.9E-324, 1.0)   0 
[1.0, 1.0)        0
[1.0, 1.0)        0
[1.0, 2.0)        3 (since we have 3 ones in x1)
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .`

I currently have the following implementation, which runs in `O(nlgn)`, assuming the sorting takes `O(nlgn)`. I'm wondering if this can be trimmed down to something lower than `O(nlgn)`. I have looked around in jblas as well and don't know of a library function for binning, if folks over here have any other insights on other native Java tricks or clever indexing scheme that they can point me to. Other suggestions on improving the code which cut down running time are also welcome.

Cutting the time down is important because the data at hand is huge.

```
public static double [] binCounts(double[] x, double[] binEdges){
    double [] ret = new double[binEdges.length - 1];
    Arrays.sort(x); // takes O(nlgn), the loop below is effectively O(n)
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < binEdges.length - 1; i++) {    
        if (binEdges[i] == binEdges[i+1])
            continue;
        for (int j = k; j < x.length; j++){
            if (x[j] >= binEdges[i+1])
                break;
            else if (x[j] >= binEdges[i] && x[j] < binEdges[i+1]){
                ret[i] += 1;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can binary search for binEdges using TreeMap:

```
public static double[] binCounts(double[] x, double[] binEdges) {
    int binEdgesSize = binEdges.length;
    NavigableMap<Double, Integer> binEdgesMap = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < binEdgesSize; ++i)
        binEdgesMap.put(binEdges[i], i);
    double [] ret = new double[binEdgesSize - 1];
    for (double d : x) {
        Entry<Double, Integer> e = binEdgesMap.ceilingEntry(d);
        if (e != null)
            ++ret[e.getValue()];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks TreeMap is a good choice, let me update code and see what time progress this gives. I'm thinking that if we do n binary searches, should'nt the time approach O(nlgn).

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar I think `O(n * log k)` where `n` is data size and `k` is binEdges size.

Comment: Agreed, it will scale depending on the size of the binEdges which in the worst case will tend to n if binEdges is of the same size as data.

Answer (score 1):

@saka1029 thank for showing the `NavigableMap` container class (I didn't know about it). It seems this could be simplified by eliminating the `ret` object and using the key directly.  Since the `binCount` map's value is an Integer, we can increment it:

```
public static double[] binCounts(double[] x, double[] binEdges) {
    int binEdgesSize = binEdges.length;
    // binCount: Key = lower edge of bin; Value = item count
    NavigableMap<Double, Integer> binCount = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < binEdgesSize; ++i)
        binCount.put(binEdges[i], 0);  // Initialize count to zero
    for (double item : x) {
        Double edge = binCount.floorKey(item);
        if (edge != null)
            binCount.get(edge)++;
    }
    return binCount.values();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at your data, you can try to recognize if they have any patterns, you can figure out any best case sorting algorithm can fits in, or get some insight on how image compress.

When considering video game objects, the coordination update on every frame update may be a little adjustment only, thus we can simply apply bubble sort and mostly it turns out to be best case in time complexity.

If you have data that the possible values are a small set of numbers,  consider something like one pass, and do the counting on the fly. So that you don't really need to having a sorting step.

A side note: My experience when data size is huge mostly also related to the space complexity as well, think about a machine with limited RAM but with a big hard disk. In that case, I would consider the bottleneck is on the hard disk reading and writing, or in a distributed system can be on the network storage. Something like your new double[binEdges.length - 1] may result OutOfMemory.

Also, try to use HashSet or similar.